# Calcular o total de pedidos e o total de pedidos do mês atual com MySQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho essa tabela de pedidos, preciso contar o total de pedidos de cada usuário e o total de pedidos de cada usuário no mês vigente

```
| id | id_user | name | data_criacao |
| 1  | 10      |Pedro | 2018-05-01   |
| 2  | 10      |Pedro | 2018-05-03   |
| 3  | 15      |Joao  | 2018-05-04   |
| 4  | 10      |Pedro | 2018-05-10   |
| 5  | 18      |Maria | 2018-05-07   |
```

Fiz esse `select` que traz o nome e o total de pedidos de cada usuário, porém preciso trazer o total de pedidos de cada usuário no mês vigente, mas não estou conseguindo.

`select name, count(*) as total from pedidos  group by id_user;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para trazer o total de pedidos de cada usuário no mês vigente, tente assim:

```
select name
      ,count(*) as total 
  from pedidos  
 where Month(data_criacao) = Month(CURRENT_DATE())
   and Year(data_criacao)  = Year(CURRENT_DATE())
 group by id_user;
```

Adicionei o filtro por ano também, para não aparecer registros de algum outro ano feito no mesmo mês, mas se desejar é só remover.

**Editado**

Já que quer mais informações tente assim:

```
select name
      ,count(*) as total_geral
      ,count(CASE WHEN Month(data_criacao) = Month(CURRENT_DATE()) and Year(data_criacao) = Year(CURRENT_DATE()) THEN 1 END) as total_usuario     
  from pedidos
 group by id_user;
```

Obs.: Não esqueça de informar na pergunta quais dados você quer como resultado

Comment: Esse select está parcialmente correto, mas além de trazer o nome, e o total do mês quero trazer o total geral de pedidos desses usuários, como fazer isso ?

Comment: Verifique a edição da minha resposta

Answer (score 0):

Oi @Daywison Ferreira Leal, 
vc precisa fazer um BETWEEN no mês atual.

seria algo assim:

```
$mes_atual = date('m');

select name, count(*) as total from pedidos WHERE mes_vigente BETWEEN $mes_atual AND $mes_atual group by id_user;
```

Nesse exemplo, falo sobre a possibilidade de vc ter uma coluna chamada mes_vigente. Vc pode utilizar a sua coluna data_criacao e fazer um explode no mes.

Comment: | name | total no mes | total geral |
| Pedro|       2             |    22          |
| Maria |       3             |    10         |

Eu precisava retornar um resultado assim.